# Populate a field that references a subdocument of another Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having difficulty populating an object that exists as a subdocument in another Model.

```
var BuildingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
address: String,
country: String
});

var CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
buildings: [BuildingSchema],
});

var MaintenanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
due: Date,
company: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Company' },      
building: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Building' },    
});
```

Query :

```
return Maintenance.find()
.populate('company building')
.exec()
.then(respondWithResult(res))
.catch(handleError(res));
```

I can confirm that the Maintenance entry in Mongodb does contain the correct Object ID for the a building stored in the matching Company.

The find() query populates "company" correctly but returns null for "building".

I'm guessing that Mongoose is not looking in the subdocuments of Company to find a match for the object id.

How do i do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I see a building field in Company but also in Maintenance, is building in maint filled? Or are you trying to populate Buildings from the Company field in maintenance ?